# Is there a scala/java equivalent of Python 3's collections.Counter

Tags: java, python, scala

I want a class that will count the the number of objects I have - that sounds more efficient that gathering all the objects and then grouping them.

Python has an ideal structure in [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), does Java or Scala have a similar type?

Comment: Java doesn't, but you can easily implement one of your own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the documentation that you linked:

> The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

Java does not have a `Multiset` class, or an analogue. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [`MultiSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) collection, that does exactly what you want.

In pure Java, you can use a `Map<T, Integer>` and the new [`merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method:

```
final Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

counts.merge("Test", 1, Integer::sum);
counts.merge("Test", 1, Integer::sum);
counts.merge("Other", 1, Integer::sum);
counts.merge("Other", 1, Integer::sum);
counts.merge("Other", 1, Integer::sum);

System.out.println(counts.getOrDefault("Test", 0));
System.out.println(counts.getOrDefault("Other", 0));
System.out.println(counts.getOrDefault("Another", 0));
```

Output:

```
2
3
0
```

You can wrap this behaviour in a `class` in a few lines of code:

```
public class Counter<T> {
    final Map<T, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(T t) {
        counts.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    public int count(T t) {
        return counts.getOrDefault(t, 0);
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
final Counter<String> counts = new Counter<>();

counts.add("Test");
counts.add("Test");
counts.add("Other");
counts.add("Other");
counts.add("Other");

System.out.println(counts.count("Test"));
System.out.println(counts.count("Other"));
System.out.println(counts.count("Another"));
```

Output:

```
2
3
0
```

Comment: Merge just made my day. Excellent.

Answer (score 10):

Not as far as I know. But scala is very expressive, allowing you to cook something like it yourself:

```
def counts[T](s: Seq[T]) = s.groupBy(x => x).mapValues(_.length)
```

Edit: Even more concise with:

```
def counts[T](s: Seq[T]) = s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: But the OP wanted something other than  "gathering all the objects and then grouping them"?

Comment: @Paul He also wanted something like `collections.Counter`. Now have a look at the python source, it looks like python does the same thing as the scala snippet I wrote. http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/collections.py

Answer (score 8):

Another scala version, doing it in one pass and avoiding `.groupBy`

```
val l = List("a", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c", "b", "d")

l.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue (0))
          { (m, el) => m updated (el, m(el)+1)}
//> res1: Map(a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 2, d -> 1)
```

or if you don't want a map with default value zero

```
l.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]()) { (m, el) => m updated (el, m.getOrElse(el,0)+1)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly you should be good with basic operations chained together. Like:

```
val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
s.groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length)) //1
s.count(_ == "apple") //2
```

With as result :

```
Map(banana -> 1, oranges -> 3, apple -> 3) //1 - result
3 //2 - result
```

Answer (score 0):

Guava MultiSet has a count method

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Brilliant, I love this library!

Answer (score 0):

Many years after I originally asked this question I realized just how trivial it was. My ultra-basic Scala solution is:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

/**
  * Created by salim on 3/10/2017.
  */
case class Counter[T]() {
  lazy val state:mutable.Map[T,Int] = mutable.HashMap[T,Int]()
  def apply(i:T):Int = state.getOrElse(i,0)
  def count(i:T):Unit = {
    val newCount = 1 + this(i)
    state += (i -> newCount)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tail recursive Scala implementation using a mutable map

```
def counter[T](s: Seq[T]) = {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map
  def counter_iter[T](s: Seq[T], m: Map[T, Int]): Map[T, Int]= {
    if (s.isEmpty) m
    else {
      m(s.head) += 1
      counter_iter(s.tail, m)
    }
  }
  counter_iter(s, Map[T, Int]().withDefaultValue(0))
}
```

to use:

```
scala> counter(List(1,1,2,2,2,3,4))
res34: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 3, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1)
```