# Counting Repeated Elements in Given Array

Tags: java, arrays

How to count repeated elements in given array? Please give me any suggestion as an alternative for this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int a[]={1,2,3,1,2,4,4,4,5};
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++)
    {
        c=1;
        for(int k=i+1;k<9;k++)
        {
            if(a[i]==a[k] && a[i]!='\0')
            {
                c++;
               // a[k]='\0';
            }
        }
        if(a[i]!='\0')
        {
            System.out.println("value is"+a[i]+"repeated in"+c);
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the array.length method instead of i!='\0' and k<9 => i<a.length and k<a.length. This way it doesn't matter how big your array is.

Comment: You should not write C in Java. What I mean is, that you should do it the java way and as @DaanMouha said, use a.length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple approach that does not require a separate data structure:

- Sort the array using [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) static method
- Now you can iterate over the array knowing all duplicates will be grouped together.  Shouldn't be hard to figure out....

Answer (score 0):

Pilfering my code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28254549/2071828):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5};
    final Counter<Integer> counter = new Counter<>();
    IntStream.of(a).forEach(counter::add);
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).forEach(i -> {
        System.out.printf("%s has a count of %s%n", i, counter.count(i));
    });
}

public static class Counter<T> {
    final Map<T, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(T t) {
        counts.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    public int count(T t) {
        return counts.getOrDefault(t, 0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 has a count of 2
2 has a count of 2
3 has a count of 1
4 has a count of 3
5 has a count of 1
```